# Is my overseas music distributor in breach of their licensing agreement? How do I get money owed to me?

Tags: licensing, international, music, distribution-terms

When I first started making music several years ago I used a service called Music Kickup; they're based in Helsinki, Finland and I am based in California, US. They take music I send them, put it on streaming platforms (spotify, apple music, etc.), and when I make money from people streaming me, those streaming services send the royalties to music kickup, then music kickup pays me. The whole "paying me" part is what's getting hung up here. They have not paid me since fall of 2016. You can look at [my payment report portal here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFlOi.jpg), accessed at the time of posting this. Section 4 of Music Kickup's licensing agreement says this about payments, I am considered the licensor here:

> Music KickUp shall provide the Licensor with a report of the sale of
>   the Licensor’s Recordings via Music KickUp Distribution Service and of
>   the accrued royalties. Music KickUp shall post the report to the
>   Licensor’s Music KickUp Account within a reasonable time from Music
>   KickUp’s receipt of such reports from the Distributors.
>
> Royalties and other related income accrued from the digital
>   distribution of the Licensor’s Recordings and received by Music KickUp
>   from the Distributors (hereinafter referred to as “Royalties”) shall
>   be credited to the Licensor’s Music KickUp Account within ninety (90)
>   days from the receipt of such Royalties by Music KickUp. For avoidance
>   of doubt, only Royalties actually received by Music KickUp from
>   Distributors shall be credited to the Licensor’s Music KickUp Account.
>   Music KickUp shall not be responsible for any delay or neglect of
>   payment by Distributors or other third parties.

You can read [the rest of their legal documentation here](https://www.musickickup.com/legal). I'm also entirely certain this is not a delay on behalf of third parties. Spotify, Apple Music, have always been quick to pass my royalties on to other distributors I've used before. I've emailed Music Kickup several times and have either been told that they're fixing it and my payments "will be available soon" (they never are) or they will just flat out stop responding. According to my math they owe me about $5,000 as of today.

I'm fairly confident what they're doing is in breach of the licensing agreement but I have no idea where to start. What can or should I do?

Comment: Google for free or low cost legal help in your area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Initiate [debt collection](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debt_collection)

**We don’t do specific legal advice here so I will just address the general question - someone owes me money; what can I do?**

Non payment of debt is not criminal behavior in most cases in most jurisdictions so collection is a private matter between you and your debtor.

There are lots of options starting from asking for your money through using a collection agency all the way to pursuing the debt through the courts.

Comment: Is it really appropriate for a moderator to answer questions that are clearly RSLA?

Comment: @Nij I don’t know because I don’t know what RSLA is.

Comment: Requesting specific legal advice.

Comment: @Nij I don't think it is - the answer certainly isn't offering any. If you think it is, VTC (vote to close)

Comment: Following a lengthy paste of their own contract, linking to their personal payment manager, describing their individual business relationship and details thereof, and asking *"what can or should I do?"* really doesn't look at all like asking for individual advice to a specific legal situation?

Comment: @Nij if you address all of that - sure. But if you just take it as “someone owes me money - what can I do?” - not so much

Comment: Then it becomes a duplicate of every other "what can I do about unpaid debts?" question and should be closed immediately anyway.